# Delete list element by index from another list value

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have list generated by an algorithm:

```
L1 = [1, 2]
```

I have a second list:

```
L2 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

How to delete the elements in `L2` by indices from `L1` values?

Here is my code which is not working:

```
L1 = [1, 2]
L2 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

for i in L1:
    for k,v in enumerate(L2):
        if i == k:
            L2.remove(v)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
L1 = [1,2]
L2 = [10,20,30,40,50]

L2 = [x for x in L2 if L2.index(x) not in L1]
```

Output:

```
[10, 40, 50]
```

Answer (score 3):

efficient:

```
>>> for i in sorted(L1, reverse=True):
...     L2.pop(i)
```

Comment: that will not work. the index of L2 was be changed after pop

Comment: @eugene, a list comprehension builds up a new list rather expensively and must handle each element in python. For the pop/del method, to have it really fast on very long L2 and short L1,  the L2 should be a linked list implementation (to avoid ASM memmove)

Comment: @julivico, the problem you think of is avoided because of the reverse=True. It does.

Answer (score 1):

If the lists are not particularly large, you could just build a new list using a list comprehension:

```
>>> L1 = [1, 2]
>>> L2 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
>>> S1 = set(L1)
>>> [el for i, el in enumerate(L2) if i not in S1]
[10, 40, 50]
```

Comment: when the set is computed before the list comp, then it brings a speed advantage over the plain `not in L1`

Answer (score 0):

Build a new list:

```
In[9]: L1 = [1,2]
L2 = [10,20,30,40,50]
In[10]: [x for i,x in enumerate(L2) if i not in L1]
Out[10]: [10, 40, 50]
```